# How to use SHA512 hashing algorithm with elliptic curve to sign, in PKCS11Interop?

Tags: pkcs#11, pkcs11interop, softhsm, hardware-security-module

In am using PKCS11Interop in C#, i got `CKR_MECHANISM_INVALID` error while trying to use method Sign. The key object i am using is of mechanism type `CKM_EC_KEY_PAIR_GEN` . but at signing time, i use mechanism `CKM_ECDSA_SHA512` .

I tried to define key mechanism as `CKM_ECDSA_SHA512` at key-pair generation time, but it seems that this key type needs some attributes that i don't know. The attributes i am using is similar to the correct version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73587070/how-to-create-a-ec-key-pair) question, but it seems using hash algorithms need some thing more.

Please guide me how should i use `SHA512` hash algorithm with `ECDSA` elliptic key.

Comment: I would invite you to this question as you wrote PKCS11-interop documentation @jariq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your unmanaged PKCS#11 library most likely does not support `CKM_ECDSA_SHA512`.

By returning `CKR_MECHANISM_INVALID` error your unmanaged PKCS#11 library is telling you that *"An invalid mechanism was specified to the cryptographic operation"*. You can use `GetMechanismInfo()` method to check whether the mechanism is supported:

```
if (!slot.GetMechanismList().Contains(CKM.CKM_ECDSA_SHA512))
    throw new Exception("Unmanaged PKCS#11 library does not support CKM_ECDSA_SHA512 mechanism");
```

However `CKM_ECDSA_SHA512` (hashing and signing) mechanism is used rather rarely. It's much more common and efficient to compute SHA512 hash in your application and then sign it with `CKM_ECDSA` (just signing) mechanism.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My soft-HSM doesn't support it, and as a solution i did digestion befor both signing and verification.